# Couchbase Filter Query -> number in range between two numbers using Spring Data Couchbase (SpEL notation).)

Tags: spring, java-8, couchbase

I'm trying to make a query in a Couchbase Database. The idea is to retrieve the elements which are in the range of two numbers. I'm using Spring Data Couchbase.

My query looks like this:

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE #{#n1ql.filter} AND $age BETWEEN minAge AND maxAge ")
    Optional<Room> findByMinAgeAndMaxAge(@Param("age") int age);
```

But

```
Unable to execute query due to the following n1ql errors: 
{"msg":"No index available on keyspace bucketEx that matches your query. Use CREATE INDEX or CREATE PRIMARY INDEX to create an index, or check that your expected index is online.","code":4000}
```

This is what I get in the console:

```
SELECT META(`bucketEx`).id AS _ID, META(`bucketEx`).cas AS _CAS, `bucketEx`.* FROM `bucketEx` WHERE `docType` = \"com.rccl.middleware.engine.repository.model.salon\" AND $age BETWEEN minAge AND maxAge ","$age":7,"scan_consistency":"statement_plus"}
```

My doubt is if I have to create the indexes for the two fields ( minAge AND maxAge) or there is another issue related with my query. I'm starting with Couchbase and not pretty sure of what is happening.

My document looks like this:

```
{
  "salons": [
    {
      "name": "salon_0",
      "id": "salon-00",
      "maxAge": 6,
      "minAge": 3
    }
  ],
  "docType": "com.rccl.middleware.engine.repository.model.salon"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The age you are looking is inside salons array. If you want document if any one of the array object matches you should use array index on on one of the filed.

```
CREATE  INDEX ix1 ON bucketEx(DISTINCT ARRAY v.maxAge FOR v IN salons END) 
    WHERE  `docType`  = "com.rccl.middleware.engine.repository.model.salon";

SELECT META( b ).id AS _ID, META( b ).cas AS _CAS,  b.* 
FROM  `bucketEx`  AS b
WHERE  b.`docType`  = "com.rccl.middleware.engine.repository.model.salon" AND 
       ANY v IN b.salons SATISFIES $age BETWEEN v.minAge AND v.maxAge END;
```

Comment: Hi My problem now is that the between is not working now as expected, I mean the query is getting all the nodes from the array

Comment: As you are doing b.* it gives all. If you don't want reconstruct array based on what you need example : Add this to projection ARRAY v FOR v in b.salons WHEN  $age BETWEEN v.minAge AND v.maxAge END AS salons